# Making one input in a tensorflow model constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following problem:
I have created a model using deepchem, which is a wrapped keras model, trained it and reloaded it. I can predict using this model without a problem.
Now I want to make a copy of this model, which has one less inputs, since one input is always constant in my use scenario and always passing it lead to errors in a function I can't edit.

```
data = np.array(data.data, dtype=float32)
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as temp_graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(self.model.session.graph.as_graph_def(),
                            input_map={self.model._input_placeholders[1].name: 
                                       tf.constant(np.array([0], dtype=float32)),})
    #self.model.session.graph = temp_graph
    #for deep explainer: replace all switched dropouts with dropouts 
    #get input tensor for this graph 
    tensors = tf.contrib.graph_editor.get_tensors(temp_graph)
    for t in tensors:
        if "input_1" in t.name:
            input_tensor = t
            break
    #reshape output --> only singletask!
    output = tf.reshape(tensors[-1], [-1, 1])
    model = (input_tensor, output)
    sess = tf.Session(graph=temp_graph)
    feed_dict = dict(zip([input_tensor], [data]))
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict))
```

In this code fragments I was able to load the graph of my model and pass a constant into its input. Now obviously I can't run this new model in the same session, since that session contains the old model. The way of running the model with the feed dict can't be changed, since it is in another package in the real scenario. I get the following error message:

```
Error while reading resource variable dense_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist.
```

The full trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_2/bias)
     [[{{node import/model/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/EXT/Tobha/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/Models.py", line 490, in <module>
    main()
  File "/EXT/Tobha/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/Models.py", line 478, in main
    evaluate()
  File "/EXT/Tobha/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/Models.py", line 445, in evaluate
    reader.explain()
  File "/EXT/Tobha/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py", line 1534, in explain
    self.explain()
  File "/EXT/Tobha/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py", line 1519, in explain
    self._explain_Gradient_SHAP(self.df)
  File "/EXT/Tobha/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py", line 2047, in _explain_Gradient_SHAP
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict))
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/EXT/Tobha/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_2/bias)
     [[node import/model/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp (defined at /eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py:2033) ]]

Original stack trace for 'import/model/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp':
  File "/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/Models.py", line 490, in <module>
    main()
  File "/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/Models.py", line 478, in main
    evaluate()
  File "/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/Models.py", line 445, in evaluate
    reader.explain()
  File "/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py", line 1534, in explain
    self.explain()
  File "/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py", line 1519, in explain
    self._explain_Gradient_SHAP(self.df)
  File "/eclipse-workspace/Bachelorarbeit/toolbox_dc_2_3_0/python_source/DataHandling.py", line 2033, in _explain_Gradient_SHAP
    tf.constant(np.array([0], dtype=float32)),})
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 443, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 236, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3751, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3751, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3641, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    ret = Operation(c_op, self)
  File "/.conda/envs/test_BA_Tobias_std_deepchem-2-3-0_py36_20200114/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

I am using tensorflow 1.14 and Python 3.6 (This can't be changed aswell)

So my problem could be solved in 2 different ways: Either I get to run the second graph with the information that is in the old session, or I get to tell the old session to use one constant input.

Thanks for any help in advance!

best regards
Tobias

Edit:
I eventually fixed this by wrapping the class I was trying to use and overwriting some methods. I think another idea could have been, to replace one Keras input with a keras constant.

Answer (score 2):

This error is a little tricky. Here's a couple of suggestions that spring to mind:

- DeepChem HEAD is now running on TensorFlow 2.X. If your problem would be easier to handle in Eager mode, that might be one option. Of course, HEAD isn't stable and there might be other issues that crop up there.
- DeepChem models are underneath the hood just made of Keras layers. If you can make a Keras model from the constituent layers of your model, then you can possibly avoid the DeepChem wrapper and solve the problem directly in Keras.

It might also help to add more information on the DeepChem model you're trying to use and the downstream function you're seeing an error in.